# How call variable from another class which is array?

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, webdriver

I use Selenium Web Driver in Eclipse with IUnit. I have code which read data from excel file. Every column is presented as array. This is code:

```
class ReadExcel {
ArrayList path_name = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList field_key = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList field_name = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList window_new = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList link = new ArrayList();
        lov_name = new ArrayList();
    public void mai() {
        int i = 0;


        String path_namel = "", field_keyl = "", field_namel = "", window_newl = "", linkl = "", lov_namel = "";
        String filename = "E:/data.xls";
        if (filename != null && !filename.equals("")) {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(filename);
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            for (int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++) {
                int j = i + 1;
                HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
                int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
                for (int r = 1; r < rows; r++) {
                    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
                    int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
                    HSSFCell cell1 = row.getCell(0);
                    path_namel = cell1.getStringCellValue();
                    HSSFCell cell2 = row.getCell(1);
                    field_keyl = cell2.getStringCellValue();
                    HSSFCell cell3 = row.getCell(2);
                    field_namel = cell3.getStringCellValue();
                    HSSFCell cell4 = row.getCell(3);
                    window_newl = cell4.getStringCellValue();
                    HSSFCell cell5 = row.getCell(4);
                    linkl = cell5.getStringCellValue();
                    HSSFCell cell6 = row.getCell(5);
                    lov_namel = cell6.getStringCellValue();

                    path_name.add(path_namel);
                    field_key.add(field_keyl);
                    field_name.add(linkl);
                    window_new.add(window_newl);
                    link.add(linkl);
                    lov_name.add(lov_namel);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my selenium test I have such cycle:

```
for (int i=0; i<path_name.length; i++){
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(path_name[i])).click();
}
```

Here I use variable `path_name` which is array and must be equal `path_name` from class ReadExcel. Actually I want use this values from excel as array. How should I call variable from ReadExcel?

**Edit**
I try use getter and setter methods.

```
int q;
String g;
public String getG() {
    return g;}
public void setG(String g) {
    this.g = g;}
public int getQ() {
    return q;}
public void setQ(int q) {
    this.q = q;}

q=path_name.size();
g=path_name.get(i).toString();
```

I my test I call variables in such way

```
ReadExcel h = new ReadExcel();
String k=   h.getG();
ReadExcel p = new ReadExcel();
int n=  p.getQ();

for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
driver.findElement(By.xpath(k)).click();}
```

Have no errors in editor, but cycle do not work. It should click on links (k), but have no effect. 
Also I try this (was suggested in first answer)

```
ReadExcel readExcel = new ReadExcel();
    ArrayList<String> path_name = readExcel.getPath_name();

    for(String pathName: path_name){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(pathName)).click();
    }
```

The same effect. It does not click on links

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to implement `setter()` and `getter()` methods in your ReadExcel class for the variables that you want to access. And they would obviously be public methods.

**Edit:**

Guessing from what you've *tried to* update and my understanding, you're doing a lot of things wrong. Assuming that you're calling your last piece of code from another class, *here's what you really should have done*:

Also, I'm assuming that you've modified your `ReadExcel` class to look something like this

```
public class ReadExcel {

    ArrayList<String> pathName      = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> fieldKey      = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> fieldName     = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> windowNew     = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> link          = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ReadExcel() {
        pathName = new ArrayList<String>();
        fieldKey = new ArrayList<String>();
        fieldName = new ArrayList<String>();
        windowNew = new ArrayList<String>();
        link      = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
    * Not so sure of this method name. But make sure that this method is called before
    * you try to call getXX() methods
    */
    public void mai() {
        String filename = "E:/data.xls";

        if(fileName == null || "".equals(fileName))
            return;

        HSSFWorkbook workBook = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        HSSFSheet sheet;
        HSSFRow row;

        int rows;

        try{
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
            workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

            for(int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < workBook.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetIndex++){
                sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);

                rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

                for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++){
                    /**
                     * Update with your own logic for retrieval
                     */
                    row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
                    if(row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells() < 6)
                        continue;

                    pathName.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                    fieldKey.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                    fieldName.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                    windowNew.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                    link.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(fileInputStream != null){
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            workBook = null;
        }
        }
    }

    /**
    * The getter/setter methods for the variables
    */
    public ArrayList<String> getPathName() {
        return pathName;
    }

    public void setPathName(ArrayList<String> pathName) {
        this.pathName = pathName;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFieldKey() {
        return fieldKey;
    }

    public void setFieldKey(ArrayList<String> fieldKey) {
        this.fieldKey = fieldKey;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(ArrayList<String> fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWindowNew() {
        return windowNew;
    }

    public void setWindowNew(ArrayList<String> windowNew) {
        this.windowNew = windowNew;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(ArrayList<String> link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

And I hope that you're somewhere calling your `mai()` method (*this name sounds really weird though*) to retrieve the data from the excel and store them in the `ArrayList` before you're trying to call the following piece of code:

```
ReadExcel readExcel = new ReadExcel();
ArrayList<String> path_name = readExcel.getPath_name();

for(String pathName: path_name){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(pathName).click();
}
```

Some pointers to your code:

- Use generics. Instead of defiing `ArrayList pathNameList` consider, using `ArrayList<String> pathNameList`
- It looks good if you use Java Naming Convention when you code. One of them is to compose method names using mixed case letters, beginning with a lower case letter and starting each subsequent word with an upper case letter. So instead of having a `getPath_name()`, consider having something like `getPathName()` or even `getPath_Name()` (*although most of us would prefer the 1st one*). [Here's a link that can help you with that.](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/naming.html)

Comment: thank you, but this part of code path_name.getPath_name();
gives error   - path_name cannot be resolved

Comment: Can you debug and see whether your path_name arraylist is empty or not?

Comment: it is not empty, as I try print its values. For example for(int j=0;j<path_name.size();j++){
 System.out.println(path_name.get(j).toString());
}. I get all values from my excel file

Comment: Hold on, shouldn't your `ArrayList` variables be part of the class and not of the methods? If you're creating them within the method itself, how can you even create and access them from outside?

Comment: I guess you mean that i edite in me ReadExcel. Sorry, I do not change it here

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert your variable into field of that class? And then add a method there to return value of that field to anyone interested.

Comment: I think first answer is something like you suggestes. I updated question

Comment: I see, now your problem doesn't see to be related to the original question. To see what's wrong one needs excel file and access to links inside. To solve this I would open particular page you start from in your tests and check that your xpathes from excel actually match right links. you can do it with dev tools in chrome or alternatives in other browsers.

Comment: Links are right, I try use them by declaring directly in my test, and it works

Comment: Are you links statically defined in html or they are generated by javascript? Or do you attach handlers dynamically? You can also try to do driver.naviate().to(driver.findElement(...).getAttribute('href')). Please let me know the result.